# Как менять текст кнопки в Kivy Python?

Tags: python, gui, kivy

При нажатии на кнопку число на кнопке должно увеличиваться на 1

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

money  = 1000
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        btn1 = Button(text = str(money),size_hint = (.4,.5), pos_hint = {"center_x" : .5})
        btn1.bind(on_press = self.click_btn)

        return btn1
    def click_btn(self,instance):
        global money
        money += 1
        btn1 = Button(text = str(money))
        return btn1
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Мне нужно чтобы на кнопке текст менялся. Прошу, помогите! Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

money  = 1000
class MainApp(App):


    def build(self):
        self.btn1 = Button(text = str(money),size_hint = (.4,.5), pos_hint = {"center_x" : .5})
        self.btn1.on_press = self.change_money
        return self.btn1
    def change_money(self):
        global money
        money=money+1
        self.btn1.text= str(money)

app = MainApp()
app.run()
```

Comment: Ну зачем вы такой говнокод рекомендуете!

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]